# Casting a const void*

Tags: c++

I have a function that returns a `const void*` and I'd like to use its information as a `char*`. I can cast it C-style fine as `(char *)variable` but when I try to use `reinterpret_cast` like `reinterpret_cast<char *>(variable)`, I get a compilation error.

Should I use a different casting method?

Comment: Cast it to a `const char *`.

Comment: Given `const void*` points to `const` data, and `char*` doesn't, that cast would be a bad idea to begin with.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Why would it work C-style then?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast

Comment: @jijemi: Because C is like the psycho ex you hope you never hear from again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either `reinterpret_cast<const char*>(variable)` or, if you really are absolutely sure you can ignore the `const` qualifier, `const_cast<char*>(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(variable))`.

Comment: first way doesn't work, can't cast that way; compilation error. second way works.

Comment: What do you mean the first way doesn't work? It should. The second is ... bad.

Comment: Sometimes you really do want to point the gun at your foot and pull the trigger.

Comment: The standard says that `static_cast` and `reinterpret_cast` from `void*` to another pointer should both work, and that they are equivalent, but perhaps your compiler is not compliant for some reason?

Comment: While I don’t know the context of this code, I want to echo the advice that this kind of cast is a code smell.

Answer (score 6):

```
const void *p;
void *q = const_cast<void *>(p);
char *r = static_cast<char *>(q);
```

The first cast gets rid of const and yields a `void *`

The second cast changes the data type and yields a `char *`

Read about the different C++ casts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-const-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used)

Answer (score 0):

Using `reinterpret_cast<char*>()` for simple types is not a good idea. Use `const char *new_variable = static_cast<const char*>(variable)`.

Also it is a bad idea to remove `const`. If you absolutely sure that the returned memory is writable, you can use then `const_cast<char*>(new_variable)`.

Comment: doesn't work this way either, can't cast that way. compilation error.

Comment: Is the compilation error a secret? This should work. Please share with the class.